# recursive Sierpinski triangle not recursive

Tags: java, recursion

I'm doing a program for a recursive Sierpinski triangle and do not know how to change the points in arrays `xm[]` and `ym[]` in order to do this. to be more specific, when i run this program, only one outlined triangle with one blue inner triangle is drawn. any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class recursiveSierpinski {
   public static void draw(int n, double x0, double y0, double x1,
      double y1, double x2, double y2) {
      // if reach base case, method return
      if (n==0) return;
      // define array xm, ym to store x and y values of midpoints
      double [] xm = new double[3];
      double [] ym = new double[3];

      // assign midpoints’ values to xm and ym
      xm[0]= (x0+x1)/2;
      xm[1]= (x1+x2)/2;
      xm[2]= (x2+x0)/2;
      ym[0]= (y0+y1)/2;
      ym[1]= (y1+y2)/2;
      ym[2]= (y2+y0)/2;

      StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
      StdDraw.filledPolygon(xm, ym); //this makes triangle
      xm[0]=xm[0]/2.0;
      ym[0]=ym[0]/2.0;
      xm[1]=xm[1]/2.0;
      ym[1]=ym[1]/2.0;
      xm[2]=xm[2]/2.0;
      ym[2]=ym[2]/2.0;

      draw(n,xm[0],ym[0],xm[1],ym[1],xm[2],ym[2]);
      draw(n,xm[1],ym[1],xm[2],ym[2],xm[0],ym[0]);
      draw(n,xm[2],ym[2],xm[0],ym[0],xm[1],ym[1]);

      // recursively draw the sub triangles (?)


     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     // N levels of recursion
     int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     // outline the triangle
     double t = Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0;
     StdDraw.line(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
     StdDraw.line(1.0, 0.0, 0.5, t);
     StdDraw.line(0.5, t, 0.0, 0.0);
     draw(N, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, t, 1.0, 0.0);
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the 'homework' tag.

Comment: yes, it's a school project, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class recursiveSierpinski {
   public static void draw(int n, double x0, double y0, double x1,
      double y1, double x2, double y2) {
      // if reach base case, method return
      if (n==0) return;
      // define array xm, ym to store x and y values of midpoints
      double [] xm = new double[3];
      double [] ym = new double[3];

      // assign midpoints’ values to xm and ym
      xm[0]= (x0+x1)/2;
      xm[1]= (x1+x2)/2;
      xm[2]= (x2+x0)/2;
      ym[0]= (y0+y1)/2;
      ym[1]= (y1+y2)/2;
      ym[2]= (y2+y0)/2;

      StdDraw.filledPolygon(xm, ym); //this makes triangle

      draw(n-1,xm[0],ym[0],xm[1],ym[1],x1,y1);
      draw(n-1,xm[1],ym[1],xm[2],ym[2],x2,y2);
      draw(n-1,xm[2],ym[2],xm[0],ym[0],x0,y0);


     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     // N levels of recursion
     int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     // outline the triangle

     double t = Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0;


     StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
     // fill arrays initially to draw black solid TRIANGLE xm, ym = 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, t, 1.0, 0.0
     StdDraw.filledPolygon(xm, ym);

     StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
     draw(N, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, t, 1.0, 0.0);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to change them any more.  Assuming that your arguments represent the points of a triangle, after your filledPolygon call you already have your points calculated.

For triangle ABC, you already found midpoints AB, BC, AC.

Therefore, you can recurse to call Sierpinski on triangle A-AB-AC, triangle AB-B-BC and triangle BC-C-AC.

In terms of your code, you would remove the changes to xm and ym after the filledPolygon() call, and call draw as such.  Note also that you want n-1 or you will recurse infinitely.

```
draw(n-1,x0,y0,xm[0],ym[0],xm[2],ym[2]);
draw(n-1,xm[0],ym[0],x1,y1,xm[1],ym[1]);
draw(n-1,xm[1],ym[1],x2,y2,xm[0],ym[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In relation to Thomas's nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8449095/5292302)

It should actually be

> ```
> draw(n-1,x0,y0,xm[0],ym[0],xm[2],ym[2]);
> draw(n-1,xm[0],ym[0],x1,y1,xm[1],ym[1]);
> ```

```
  draw(n-1,xm[1],ym[1],xm[2],ym[2],x2,y2);
```

hence according to me last line should be different.